# Multiple connection strings with MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So the critical parts of my web config looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppConnection" connectionString="Server=100.100.100.100;Database=AppDB;User Id=user;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="MemberConnection" connectionString="Server=100.100.100.100;Database=aspnetdb;User Id=user;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and within the membership providers section:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="MemberConnection"
      applicationName="Consulate"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

As written, when I register, it connects to the incorrect database.

However, if I change all instances of "MemberConnection" to "DefaultConnection" it works.

Why does it have to use "Default" as part of the connection string name?

Comment: What Membership provider are you using?  Default, Simple, Identity?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Default

Answer (score 2):

Within IdentityModels.cs, there the constructor for ApplicationDbContext inherited a hard-coded "DefaultConnection" string.

Changed that to the connection string that correlates to the aspnetdb (membership) and it worked.